# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, oracle, tomcat, servlets

There is so many of this error in stackoverflow but I could not resolver my issue from is. Below is my simple configurations :

**context.xml** from my TOMCAT server where I have configured a datasource for accessing my oracle 11g server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!--Oracle DataSource-->
        <Resource
             name="jdbc/MonDataSource"
             auth="Container"
             type="javax.sql.DataSource"
             driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
             url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"
             username="system"
             password="Azerty123"
             connectionProperties="SetBigStringTryClob=true"
             accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
             maxTotal="60"
             maxIdle="20"
             maxWaitMillis="10000"
         />

</Context>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**servlet-context.xml** to show my bean configuration

```
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/MonDataSource"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="ArticleDAO" class="com.projet.testjdbc.ArticleDAOImpl">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:ref bean="dataSource" />
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

I don't know if it'll be usefull but you have below my **controller** action

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleDAO aricleDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value="/liste")
    public ModelAndView home() throws IOException{
        List<Article> listArticles = aricleDAO.list();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
        model.addObject("articleListe", listArticles);
        return model;
    }

}
```

**EXCEPTIONS MESSAGES EXCERPT**

> exception
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79
>     ...
>
> root cause
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'aricleDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ArticleDAO': Failed to introspect bean class [com.projet.testjdbc.ArticleDAOImpl] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     ...
>
> root cause
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ArticleDAO': Failed to introspect bean class [com.projet.testjdbc.ArticleDAOImpl] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:269)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1091)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     ...
>
> root cause
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper
>     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>     java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>     org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
>     org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
>     org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:247)
>     ...
>
> root cause
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper
>
> > org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
> >     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
> >       java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
> >       java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
> >       java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
> >     org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
> >     org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
> >       ...

Comment: And stack trace is... ?

Comment: @StanislavL I just added an excerpt of the trace (each section of it)

Comment: Your application is missing the spring-jdbc jar.

Comment: @SteveC But I have added the JAR in my Java Build path Libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper
```

Looks like you miss a dependency. Add this to maven (if you use it)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

If not add the .jar to classpath

Comment: Problem solved. I was missing both `spring-jdbc` and `spring-dao`. I have install both in my Maven local repository. Do I need to add `<dependency>` in my pom.xml and add the JAR to the build path libraries every time I need them ?

Comment: Yes. You need the classes if you would like to work with DB using spring jdbc.